# Are R-134a quick-couple adapters compatible with R-1234yf systems?

Tags: r134a, r1234yf

In other words, do R-1234yf systems use the same charging port design as R-134a?

[image: Quick Couple Adapters]

Comment: This question was answered by you in this answer if you read carefully what you quoted : https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/54775/10976

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not. According to [this website](http://www.underhoodservice.com/underhood-update-on-r-1234yf-refrigerant/):

> Vehicles with R-1234yf have different service fittings than R-134a vehicles to prevent cross-contamination with different refrigerants.

You can purchase new couplers which will convert the old R-134a gauge manifolds to the new R-1234yf couplers.

[image]

Comment: Funny how the size was changed to avoid cross-contamination but then adapters are available to enable just that